# why my cookies doesn't set in next js app on vercel?

Tags: cookies, next.js, vercel

I set cookie after login by with node js and it works correctly on localhost but it doesn't work when I deploy my next js app on vecel.
I think it is because my cookie domain.
my domain on vercel is https://flight-six.vercel.app
I write `https://flight-six.vercel.app`
and `.https://flight-six.vercel.app`
in the domain of cookie but still it doesn't work.
what I have to do?please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
domain : "flight-six.vercel.app"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).